# Regex to check for a number of char occurences in string

Tags: regex

I am quite stuck with this one, but it should be fairly easy. For creating a rule in one of the e-mail systems, I need to supply a RegEx that will check specific part of the header of e-mail message. So, I would like to check if the number of occurences of `@`char in one string that is consisting of names and e-mail messages is over 10.

I've tried with `^[@]{10,1}?`but that doesn't work for me, this one actually checks if I have 10 conescutive `@`in string.

Example string is
`John Doe<john.doe@.joe.com>,Jane Doe<jane.doe@jane.com>,Jack Doe<jack.doe@jack.com` etc. 
If there is more than 10 occurences of `@`I would like the expression to evaluate to true

Comment: Would `(@.*?){10}` do what you need? *"Over 10"* would actually need 11 in the regex.

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you very much!

Comment: It is more efficient to use `@(?:[^@]*@){10}`. I guess more than 10 means 11 or more.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you're just testing the regex and not saving the result anywhere, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 
[`(?:@.*?){10}@`](https://regex101.com/r/RALLcw/1) to check there are at least 11 `@` symbols (since you wrote "over 10" and "more than 10")

Comment: I would insist on following best practices when writing regexps. If in this case it does not matter much, in future, in longer patterns, following best practices will save hours of work. Use `@(?:[^@]*@){10}`. Also, `[^@]` matches linebreaks, `.` does not always match line breaks in regex.

Comment: Replacing `.*?` with `[^@]*` will decrease matching time significantly.

Comment: I think the time needed to access the email header is much more significant any way.